# Laravel 5 date mutator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, php-carbon

I am trying to use a accessor mutator on my date but getting all sorts of errors.

Currently:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return $date->diffForHumans();
}
```

But I get:

```
Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string
```

I just want to use the Carbon functions on the created at date but always get this error.

Any help?

Comment: You don't want to use the date function of php?

Comment: Add created_at to your model's $dates array

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute()
{
   return $this->attributes['created_at']->diffForHumans();
}
```

Anyway, by doing that you'll make it impossible to get the original value. So I suggest that you just create a getter for an attribute with another name, e.g.:

```
public function getHumanCreatedAtAttribute()
{
   return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

and then use it as

```
$mode->human_created_at;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in your `BaseModel`:

```
public function getDates()
{
    return ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

This will ensure `created_at` and `updated_at` fields will be treated as `Carbon` objects.